# What exactly defines a "widget"?

Tags: widget

I've seen widget used like a rather technical term, and the W3C has specifications for it. But Wikipedia says that a widget is just a piece of code that can be re-used in different ways. SE's definition for the widget tag doesn't fit either of those descriptions. What's a widget then?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it depends on the context. On Android, a widget is an application that can be interacted with from the home screen. At my job, you can add widgets to your personalized intranet home page. But there's also the software application aspect, usually said to give a measure of the size of the application. So it has multiple meanings: a generally small GUI element devoted to a single purpose/application, or a small application as a whole.

Haha, and if you mouse-over the "widget" tag, it says something similar. Perhaps someone should expand the tag description.

Comment: Pretty much dead-on, a widget is just a small piece of code or functionality that does only one thing.

Comment: @TheEliteNoob The word "widget" does carry a visual connotation, so it has to be visible somehow (so it isn't just a code library or a bunch of methods, in my mind anyway)