# What exactly is a widget?

Tags: java, android, view, widget

I found some conflicting definitions on the term. On http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html,
the author defined widgets as "View is the base class for widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components (buttons, text fields, etc.)", bascially used to create interactive UI components. However on on another StackOverFlow question [What exactly defines a "widget"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911249/what-exactly-defines-a-widget), an answer was "application that can be interacted with from the home screen". My question is that in terms of android, does the term widget refer to the tool used to create the ui components or the ui components themselves? Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: `Combination of views`

Comment: I'd opt for the second definition

Comment: widget is entity by which user can interact perform some actions on it. In general all the view are called widgets. More precisely its smallest component that is complete in its own and go in any other widget with attributes if set properly.

Comment: It is a fictional product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attending to developers, a widget is a subclass of View. Examples of widgets are TextViews, ImageViews, WebViews...

Attending to final users, widgets or app widgets (like Niek Haarman has said) are small apps that display info of some kind in the home screen or lock screen, you can find a lot of "app widgets" in Google Play. Weather widgets, financial widgets, email widgets...

Comment: Those last group of widgets are often called *app widgets*.

Answer (score 0):

Both the definations are correct.. widget is a view.. while developing we see textview,imageview etc which are created for the developers to use.. the widgets we see on the homescreen are developed by the developerss for the users to use ..

Shortly widgets are those which are created for developers and also created by developers..:)

Answer (score -1):

I believe a widget is kind of a desktop icon or an iPhone home screen miniature app. I also believe widget is short for "web gadget".

Comment: kind of like how igoogle had all those fun add on's etc.

Comment: `widget is short for "web gadget".` This is incorrect; [widget is an alteration of the word 'gadget', and was first used in 1926](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/widget). Also, ["web widget"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_widget) is a valid term.

Answer (score -1):

`A widget is a stand-alone application that can be embedded into third party sites by any user on a page where they have rights of authorship (for example: a web page, blog, or profile on a social media site). Widgets allow users to turn personal content into dynamic web apps that can be shared on websites where the code can be installed.`