# What is a w3 widget

Tags: html, widget, web-component

I've recently run into this in a project of mine and I'm really surprised that I've never heard of this thing at all ever. What is a W3 widget?

The documentation for a w3 widget is here: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/

Which forgive me for saying doesn't make any sense at all. Could someone provide a tl;dr version of what a W3 widget is?

Comment: Is there really no one who knows what these are?

Comment: The question is legitimate. The one answer is dealing with the generic "widget" definition. I did find a good description in

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered in a previous question, can't add a duplicate notice so leaving in here:

***"A widget is just a small piece of code or functionality that does only one thing."***

See this answer:
[What exactly defines a "widget"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911249/what-exactly-defines-a-widget)