# What is a Widget in React and how it is different from a normal React Component/Class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget

I searched on this question but all I got is we can make a Button, Scroll bar etc using a Widget. And we can create it using *React.createClass* (which I think is no longer available in latest versions of react).

**Can someone please give me a sample code to show how exactly this react widget created and how technically (functionally) it is different from a normal react Class/Component??**

**Edit:
What are the application areas where we can use a react widget??? I'm not clear why we should create a react widget??**

Comment: *we can make a Button, Scroll bar etc using a Widget* - what exactly are you talking about? React doesn't have such term. It's specific to sources you read and doesn't make much sense without a context.

Comment: react-widgets is a suite of high-quality input components built for React. So I think they are normal components, too. [react-widgets](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/).

Comment: I don't get what you mean, 'widget' isn't a React specific term. A widget is just a GUI element designed to interact with some application or service. For example, at work we have a Vue application that uses Auth0 for authentication and the Auth0 login modal is made in React. It's a React widget. Asking the difference between widgets and react classes is like asking the difference between search boxes and React components. It makes no sense, they aren't really comparable.

Comment: Ohh. I just read this somewhere, when I was reading about general Widgets. And not specifically about react widgets. I'm still unclear about this whole Idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911249/what-exactly-defines-a-widget

Comment: Then what are the application areas where we can use a react widget??? I'm not clear why we should create a react widget??

Comment: Because you need something to click. A piece of UI that you click is often called a widget. A widget that is built with React will be a component - just because we have nothing to choose from, React is about components. You're asking about colloquial term that doesn't make sense without a context. 'Widget' is a synonym for  'thing'.

Comment: @estus
Thanks. These are the basics I was searching. Any link for more detailed info

Comment: You can search for 'javascript widget' or 'react widget' to understand in which context this word is used. Again, this is not technical term and depends on the context. Iframe React app that contains search form could be called a widget as well, in the context of whole page. While technically it's React component.